# Linking from one tab to another tab and linking to a specific tab from a different page

Tags: jquery

Sorry for asking this question but I am new to this and having a hard time figuring it out even when looking at some of the other solutions on this site.

I am trying to get links from test1 tab to switch to the appropriate tab (ex: link for test 3 makes content of test 3 appear.

The other question I had was how do I link from one page (ex: index.html) to test4 of tabs page.

Enclosed below is links to all the files for my test site.

#### CSS

http://www.sukhanidesign.com/tab/ 
css/tabs.css
 
            css/red-style.css

#### JS

js/tabs.js
            js/tabs2.js
            js/main.js
            js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

#### HTML

http://www.sukhanidesign.com/tab/tabs.html

Comment: links give 403 error. Please make a fiddle with necessary js on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wAjwU/2/ is the fiddle